# Building one to many live streaming platform

Tags: node.js, ffmpeg, socket.io, webrtc, video-streaming

I want to build a one to many users streaming app where admin can stream video and users can view that video in live. I have to use node.js. which is best approach and what are good tools for that.
Does using webrtc one to many affect performance at large scale?
Suggestions please...
Thanks

Comment: I strongly recommend SRS (https://github.com/ossrs/srs) as a good solution for both live streaming and WebRTC one-to-many platforms.

Answer (score 1):

given my extensive experience in the subject and the use of many WebRTC libraries, I would recommend that you use an SFU or MCU where you can cover high-level conferences on a large scale, I do not recommend the use of WebRTC one to one due to you'll no doubt have a lot of performance issues.

My recommendation is that you use an SFU or MCU library, for example:
https://github.com/livekit/livekit

LiveKit is easy to use, great scalability (depends on your server), it has tools to measure the server so you know if you need a better one, it also has many server-side and client-side SDKs such as: Javascript, ReactNative, Flutter, Android and Server Side: PHP, Nodejs, Etc.

It also allows you to have total control of the room, who can enter a room, who can broadcast, etc.

I hope my answer helps you.